# TypeScript Record<K,T> doesn't check key type?

Tags: typescript

I was playing with TypeScript a little bit, how come this works in TypeScript?

```
interface A {
    a: string; 
}

const a: A = {
    'a': 'b'
}

function foo(r: Record<number, string>) {
    console.log(r);
}

foo(a); // prints {"a": "b"}
```

I was expecting `Record<string, string>` to work and not `Record<number, string>`. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: It does work for me, see here: https://tsplay.dev/w180GW It says, "Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<number, string>'. Index signature is missing in type 'A'."

Comment: Correct. sorry I was looking at the wrong thing.  It's actually not working for Record<string, string> either. why is this case? I can close the question

Comment: Interestingly, the error shows for `foo(r: Record<string, string>)` which one would expect to work. However, `foo(r: Record<number, any>)` works.

Comment: If you use `type` instead of `interface` as here https://tsplay.dev/WKkgZW things work

Comment: Interestingly strange. Thanks!